# SwiftUI mode.wrapped.value() lifts scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As it's common practice to use, I have LazyVStack inside my scroll View.

I have 3 views.

1st view contains Header which can be shown or hidden, and all other content goes under the header

2nd view with button to present 3rd view (when 3rd view is presented I want header to disappear, it does, but there is blank space under, and when I come back to previous view with mode.wrappedValue.dismiss() it's lifted and I cannot access the last image from 2nd view.

My repo: https://github.com/martynasNarijauskas/swiftui
My code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

struct TestView: View {

    let hideUserInfo = NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("HideUserInfo"))

    let showUserInfo = NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("ShowUserInfo"))

    @State
    var shouldShowHeader = true

    @State
    var selection: Int? = 0

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if shouldShowHeader {
                    Text("Test")
                }
                NavigationView {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.green.ignoresSafeArea()
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: TestView2(),
                            tag: 1,
                            selection: $selection,
                            label: {
                                EmptyView()
                            })
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                selection = 1
                            },
                            label: {
                                Text("Button")
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
    }.onReceive(hideUserInfo) { info in
        self.shouldShowHeader = false
    }
    .onReceive(showUserInfo) { info in
        self.shouldShowHeader = true
    }

    }
}


struct TestView2: View {
    @State
    var selection: Int? = 0

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color.green.ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: OpenedView(),
                    tag: 1,
                    selection: $selection,
                    label: {
                        EmptyView()
                    })
                Button(
                    action: {
                        selection = 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("Button")
                    }
                )
                LazyVStack {
                    Image(systemName: "star").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Image(systemName: "star").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Image(systemName: "star").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Image(systemName: "star").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Image(systemName: "star").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Image(systemName: "star").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Image(systemName: "star").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Image(systemName: "star").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ShowUserInfo")))
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}


struct OpenedView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    @State
    var selection: Int? = 0

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("Go bck")
                    }
                )
            }.onAppear {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "HideUserInfo")))
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's because .onAppear notification on the 3rd screen causes the entire NavigationView to move. I would recommend removing the VStack on the TestView and just use a ZStack(alignment: .top) to put the header on top of the NavigationView. This would make the NavigationView the full screen size. Then add .padding() or something within the TestView to move the content down to account for being under the header. This way, when you "hide" the header, it doesn't actually change the NavigationView. It only changes the header view.

Comment: @nicksarno well true, if I remove VStack and add padding to navigation view, it works, but if I open "OpenedView" padding still exists, and if I change padding according is header presented or not, it still redraws all navigation view. Or I understood something incorrectly?

Comment: Don't put the padding on the entire NavigationView, put it on the content within the first view.